# How to know if a webfont is free?

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts

The question seems trivial, but I need to know if a particular font is free to be embedded in a website as a webfont or I must purchase a license in order to do it.
Is there some good practice to ensure if a webfont is free or not?

(eg. the font I'm searching for is Futura Md BT Medium, I know Futura family shouldn't be free but if you google for it you'll find lots of sites that offer webfonts where you can download it for free and very few where you need to pay a license, usually to purchase the whole font family for desktop)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the font is available on Google Fonts tool (http://www.google.com/fonts). If not, it might be it is not an open-source font.

(Futura is not open-source)